# Creating and Saving Records for Rspec Unit Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd, bdd

I've recently been doing about 10 hours a week of Rails TDD with Rspec for a client of mine. I find that a lot of tests I need to write require there to be records in the database, BUT from what I've learned, it's not good practice for tests to refer to a database. How can I create/save a record in my test so that the test can then run successfully or is there a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Have you already looked at FactoryBot factories?

Comment: Most of the times you can use mocks to fake real objects, other times you don't actually need the record saved but a new unpersisted object works too. Some times the database must be used, it depends on what you are testing. I don't think there's a general solution, you should at least give some examples of tests you want help to receive better advices.

Comment: The idea is that, before you create (or, persist) an object, you should ask yourself whether you actually need that object to be stored in the database...or if instantiating the object is sufficient. This is true even if you are using something like FactoryBot ([i.e. there are times when you should use build_stubbed instead of create](https://medium.com/@DmytroVasin/speed-up-your-tests-via-build-stubbed-f1926863b3d7).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to check some gems to assist you.

At very least:

- [factory_bot_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails)

It allows you for basically anything you might need.

Often times you don't want to actually persist objects to db, the gem covers you there as well providing you with `build` methods.

The DSL is clear and hey, it's [thoughtbot](https://thoughtbot.com)'s product - quality guaranteed :)